# Handling Django Rest Framework 404 page directed to react app's home/index

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-react

I have DRF project and the react project is also within the Django project as an application. The name of the react application is `frontend`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
....
'frontend'
]
```

The structure of the frontend is as follows,

[image]

The only code in the project is in views,

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "build/index.html")
```

And the URL is,

```
from frontend.views import index
urlpatterns += [path("", index, name="index")]
```

Now what I was trying to do is, if the browser's URL response is 404, then instead of showing django's 404 page I would like to go the home/index of the `frontend` react app. I tried to add `handler404 = 'frontend.views.index'` in `urls.py`, but it shows 500 internal error instead of 404 or the index of react app.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me in regular django project.

```
def handler404(request, exception):
    return render(request, '404.html', status=404)
```

Here, `404.html` is my custom template file.

and in my main urls.py:

```
handler404 = myapp.views.handler404
handler500 = myapp.views.handler500
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from frontend.views import index
urlpatterns += [path("", index, name="index")]
```

In above code you define that any url comes that will goes to home page becuase you used  "". You have to use url regex for index page.

```
from django.urls import re_path, include    
urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^$', index, name="index")]
```

This will work for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but it did not work for me.